# Specifying and printing columns in an Oracle Database

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm having trouble specifying what data I wish to output, what I'm trying to do is print all the the recipe title's contained in the recipe table.

```
$stid2 = oci_parse($conn, 'select recipetitle from recipes.recipe');
oci_execute($stid2);

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid2, OCI_ASSOC)) {
  echo "<p>Sorry, there are no titles</p>";
    } else {
        echo '<p> <b>Recipe Title: </b>' . $row['recipetitle'] . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Is that even possible? I just get the 'unidentified index' error.

Thanks

Comment: `While` / `else` doesn't exist in php.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, `while` / `else` doesn't exist in php.

Instead, try :

```
$stid2 = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT `recipetitle` FROM `recipes`.`recipe`');
oci_execute($stid2);

//Output var
$output = '';

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid2, OCI_ASSOC)) {
    $output .= '<p> <b>Recipe Title: </b>' . $row['recipetitle'] . '</p><br>';
}

//Ternary test
$output == '' ? echo "<p>Sorry, there are no titles</p>" : echo $output;
```